# How to correctly do type conversions in dart

Tags: flutter, dart, casting

I'm building a flutter app that uses Dog API but I am failing to convert the type of a `Map` to `Map<String, List<String>>`

I have tried to use `map.cast<String,List<String>>()` but while not producing an error when I try to return the result (after specifing that the function returns a `Map<<String,List<String>>>`), when I run `print(map.runtimeType);` the output is `CastMap<String, dynamic, String, List<String>>` and not `Map<<String,List<String>>>`

```dart
Future<Map<String,List<String>>> getbreeds() async{
    var json=await http.get('https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all');
    var linkedHashMap =Map.from(jsonDecode(json.body)) ;
    var map=linkedHashMap['message'].cast<String,List<String>>();
    print(map.runtimeType);
    return map;
  }
```

I expect the output of `print(map.runtimeType);` to be `Map<<String,List<String>>>` but instead, I get `CastMap<String, dynamic, String, List<String>>`

Answer (score 2):

A `CastMap<String, dynamic, String, List<String>>` is a subtype of `Map<String, List<String>>` so that isn't a problem here. It's comparable to a situation where you specify a return type of `num` and the concrete value you return is an `int`.

The issue you're going to hit is that when you read a value from the map you'll have a `List<dynamic>` instead of a `List<String>`. You need to change the runtime types on the inner values as well.

```
var map = (linkedHashMap['message'] as Map).map((key, value) => MapEntry<String, List<String>>(key, List.from(value));
```

Comment: this code produces the following error: `type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr<Map<String, List<String>>>'`

Comment: Ah, probably missing some amount of inference because the call to `.map()` is on a static `dynamic`, not a `Map`. Will need to either cast the value to a `Map` (I'll edit my answer to this), or alternatively specify `.map<String, List<String>>((key, value) => ...)`